# What are Facebook, Twitter, and YouTube's policy toward Kashmir?

Tags: social-media, kashmir

I heard that Facebook and other social media platforms are censoring any news or information regarding the Indian administered Kashmir which goes against the Indian government's policy toward Kashmir. How true is that?

What are Facebook, Twitter, and YouTube's policy toward Kashmir?

Comment: [this link here](https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-news-technology/posts-on-kashmir-deities-tricolour-facebook-flags-locally-illegal-content-5536763/) could help. From India perspective

Answer (score 1):

I can no find evidence that these companies have a specific policy about Kashmir in particular, but the enforcement of their community standards have been perceived as censorship on multiple occasions.

[Here](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/jul/19/facebook-under-fire-censoring-kashmir-posts-accounts) is an article on the Guardian from 2016 where several users describe Facebook account terminations which those users felt were not justified. In some cases, Facebook has apologized for and reversed these decisions. But in general, Facebook issued a statement defending these actions as follows:

> “There is no place on Facebook for content that praises or supports terrorists, terrorists organisations or terrorism. We welcome discussion on these subjects but any terrorist content has to be clearly put in context which condemns these organisations and or their violent activities. Therefore, **profiles and content supporting or praising Hizbul Mujahideen and Burhan Wani are removed as soon as they are reported to us**. In this instance, some content was removed in error, but this has now been restored.”

Comment: So, how do they define and decide who is terrorist and who is not? E.g. Abdullah Ozalan is a terrorist in Turkey, but a freedom fighter in Kurdistan of Iraq, etc.

Comment: My understanding is that Facebook follows the local policies of individual countries, e.g. [it blocks PKK content in Turkey](https://www.dw.com/en/facebook-censorship-of-pro-kurdish-political-party/a-17199752) but not elsewhere because most other countries (like the US, right or wrong) don't consider PKK to be terrorist organization.